# Why doesn't this piece of Javascript code work on my browsers?

Tags: javascript

```html
<button id="myButton">You want to click me</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementByID("myButton").onclick = function() {

    alert("Hi!");

  }
</script>
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with this, please?

Comment: Where is your button html?

Comment: it should work as-shown

Comment: It's a typo. document.getElementById, not document.getElementByID

Answer (score 4):

It should be `getElementById`, not `getElementByID` (the last letter should be lower case).

Comment: Thank you. Wow, the lower case and upper case matter in Javascript? that is very painful.

Comment: @JessicaTaylor - Yes, JavaScript is case-sensitive. Once you get used to it, it actually becomes quite a nice feature.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your syntax error, some javascript validators would flag your missing semicolon at the end of your function.

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick=function() {
 alert("Hi!");
};
```

To find the getElementById error, if you're using IE, just open the IE developer tools, then navigate to the Console tab.  You would have seen an error like:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementByID'
```

Comment: Thank you. I run my codes in chrome.